# Horror TV series episode wherein a girl draws her father with no eyes

Tags: story-identification

It starts with a young girl drawing a house in a open field. She draws a hill and a tree, and then her dad standing by the tree - each time she draws it. it appears in the landscape. She looks up the hill, and her dad is standing there. He calls out to her by name several times, and then screams out "I HAVE NO EYES!!!" (She forgot to draw his eyes).

In the rest of the show, he chases her through the house, stumbling and screaming and trying to get her...it was awesome, and has stuck with me since I saw it, but I haven't seen it since.

I think it was the eighties...maybe early nineties, but I think it was the eighties.

Answer (score 10):

It's actually a film called '[Paperhouse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098061/)' made in 1988.

> Mark is a cripple but wants to leave the house, obligingly Anna draws
>   in a lighthouse (a place to go to) but still the problem remains mark
>   can't walk. So Anna decides to draw her father in. she gets her pencil
>   out and gets too work, but the outcome is deformed and unsettling Anna
>   particularly dislikes his eyes. Quote "he looks like madman". So Anna
>   tries to rub him out and start again, but the pencil proves indelible
>   (that means nothing can be rubbed out). Then **Anna loses her temper and
>   crosses out her father's eyes! I leave you too find out for you self
>   the terrible consequences of the rash action.**

### Trailer